# Verifying a notification signature (PHP)

Tags: php, notifications, signature

I need to validate a signature for a callback from ankoder.com who provide the following description:

It is the URL-escaped string of Base64-encoded HMAC-SHA1 digest of your private key and the URL-unescaped message.

```
$passkey = urlencode(base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', urldecode($str), $private_key, true)));
```

They provide the following Ruby example

```
encoded_signature = CGI.escape Base64.encode64(HMAC::SHA1::digest(private_key, CGI.unescape(message))).strip
```

I run this on sample data I have returned from a callback but am not getting the same signature.  How do I replicate the Ruby code in PHP?

**Edit**
  The issue was trailing whitespace being sent through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PHP code matches the Ruby code. The problem must be somewhere else.

Check if the key is correct and the message is parsed correctly (urldecode, then json_decode).

Comment: While I have not yet found a solution I am now fully confident that the error lies in the input string and as a result I am accepting this answer.